# Update INSTALLDIR for multi-instance installation

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I'm creating an installation package for a Windows Service using InstallShield 2012. I want the user to be able to install multiple named instances of my service on the same machine. (If you're a SQL Server user, I want to do the same as it does with named instances.)

What I'd like to be able to do is get the user to enter the name of the instance they're installing (INSTANCE_NAME) and append it to INSTALLDIR. I've created a screen to capture the INSTANCE_NAME but I can't work out how to append it to the INSTALLDIR. Do I need to write a script or can I do it using the 'Directory' table?

e.g
INSTALLDIR => c:\Program Files\My Company\My Product\My Instance\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete solution is more complex then what I'm about to say but basically you can do it with a Type 35 ( Set Directory ) Custom Action.

Set INSTALLDIR = [ProgramFilesFolder]My Company\My Product[INSTANCENAMEPROPERTY]

You then use a Control Event on the Next Button of your dialog to call the custom action before proceding to the next dialog ( New Dialog )

Answer (score 0):

In Installshield, go to Release>Config. In the multiple instances tab for each instance set the InstallDir and ProductCode and ProductName.